# No action is specified in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to html. I am working on a form data which looks like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}Validator{% endblock %} 
{%block page_class %}validator{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-20-percent">
    <img class="on-page-logo" src="{{ client_logo_path }}" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-80-percent">
    Template Uploader
    <div>
        {% if errors %}
        <div>
            Errors
            <ul style="color: red;">
                {% for error in errors %}
                <li class="">{{ error }}</li> {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endif%}
        <!-- PLAN-1400 -->
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"><br /> <br /> <input
                type="submit" value="Validate">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
{% endblock %} {% block requirified_js %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var CMO = CMO || {};
</script>
<script
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pkg/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.min.js') }}"></script>

<script
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/validator.js', v=STATIC_VERSION) }}"></script>
<script
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pkg/bootstrap/3.3.2/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Please look at the form tags, I have not specified the action here, 
so what happens when I click on the Validate button.

If the answer is "It redirects to itself" what does it exactly mean?

In my case it is entering into a function which it also enters when I just launch the page i.e without clicking button

Comment: submit button post to itself when form action type is POST. This is your case.

Comment: WHat is the meaning of "post to Itself"

Comment: This means that if your page URL is example.com/page.html, the form will request the page.html file from your server. You may need to read about client/serve architecture

Comment: @ShivanandT, refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form, it may help you for HTML forms.

Comment: Thank you Anil and Mouneer,